# remove a vertex of a 2-connected graph without break 2-connected

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, graph-connectivity

suppose $G$ is 2-connected and $G$ is not a cycle, is it possible to prove that there exists a vertex $v$ such that $G-v$ is still 2-connected?

$G-v$ means remove $v$ from vertex and all incident edges

Comment: In the '30s, Whitney showed that a graph $G$ is 2-connected if and only if it has an ear decomposition (for instance, check out https://math.la.asu.edu/~andrzej/teach/mat416/proofs4.pdf for the proof). Your graph isn't a cycle, so the decomposition is nontrivial. Does this help with your problem?